# How to implement ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) into WordPress?

Tags: api

How can I develop my ERP software in garments industry by using Wordpress? Is it best to use WordPress to use a ERP using WordPress. Have any readymade ERP in WordPress?

Comment: I edited your question, adding "Enterprise Resource Planning" to the title because I think not everybody will know what ERP stands for… I hope I was right with my guess? Also: you should probably give a few more details what you are actually trying to achieve – Do you want to build an ERP-Plugin for WordPress? Or are you looking for an API to connect WP with your ERP system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mark Kuplun is 100% correct.

You can try  [We ERP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/erp/). You need lot of customize if you fulfill requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress is a CMS, not a platform for ERP. You can force wordpress to be the core of an ERP system, and if the relevant organization is small enough it might even work, but it is unlikely to scale. There is a reason why ERP systems take long time and a lot of money to implement even when using an ERP product/framework.